# Flask Login not detecting Anonymous Users

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I'm using Python 3.4. I have a route like this:

```
@user.route('/manage_users', methods=['GET'])
@login_required
@any_administrator_required
def manage_users():
    print('lkjrd')
```

`any_administrator_required` is a decorator of mine defined like so:

```
def any_administrator_required(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
        if not current_user.data['primary_administrator'] and not current_user.data['secondary_administrator']:
            abort(403)
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorated_function
```

And my logged in user class:

```
class LoggedInUser(UserMixin):
    data = {}
    def is_authenticated(self):
        return True
    def is_active(self):
        return True
    def is_anonymous(self):
        return False
    def get_id(self):
        return str(self.data['user'])
```

I'm able to go to my login or logout page and log in and log out normally, but when I go to a route decorated with `login_required` when not logged in, it isn't redirecting or aborting with a 401. When I go to `/manage_users` when not logged in, it passes the `login_required` decorator and goes to the `any_administrator_required` where it fails because the anonymous user class doesn't have the `self.data` attribute. I've tried moving the decorators around so that it was in this order:

```
@user.route('/manage_users', methods=['GET'])
@any_administrator_required
@login_required
def manage_users():
    print('lkjrd')
```

But it still has the same result. My `unauthorized_callback`:

```
@login_manager.unauthorized_handler
def unauthorized_callback():
    return redirect(url_for('login', next=request.path))
```

My login snippet:

```
logged_in_user = LoggedInUser()
logged_in_user.data = user_data     
login_user(logged_in_user)
session['logged_in'] = True
```

My logout route:

```
@logout.route('/logout', methods=['GET'])
@login_required
def logout():
    logout_user()
    session.pop('logged_in', None)
    return redirect(url_for('main'))
```

And of course, going to `/logout` while not logged in just redirects to the main page, no 401.

User loader:

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    r = REQUEST_USER_DATA_FROM_API
    logged_in_user = LoggedInUser()
    logged_in_user.data = r.json()
    return logged_in_user
```

Comment: What does your [`user_loader`](https://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#flask.ext.login.LoginManager.user_loader) look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After tracing through the `flask_login.py` module, `login_manager._login_disabled` was True because testing was enabled. And when `_login_disabled` is True, the `login_required` decorator does nothing.

Code for `login_required`:

```
@wraps(func)
def decorated_view(*args, **kwargs):
    if current_app.login_manager._login_disabled:
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    elif not current_user.is_authenticated():
        return current_app.login_manager.unauthorized()
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
```